# Internal Server Error while entering points using JSON in InfluxDB

Tags: python, json

I am trying to Enter points using JSON in InfluxDB version 0.9. I run localhost:8083 on my browser. It is enabling me to create a DB, but when I try to enter the points using JSON, it is shoeing 'Internal Server Error'. I tried to do the same using Python API for Influx DB.

```
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
json_body = [
    {
        "name": "cpu_load_short",
        "tags": {
            "host": "server01",
            "region": "us-west"
            },
        "timestamp": "2009-11-10T23:00:00Z",
        "fields": {
            "value":0.64
            }
        }
    ]
client = InfluxDBClient('localhost', 8086, 'root', 'mydb')
client.create_database('mydb')
client.write_points(json_body)
```

For the `clients.write_points(json_body)`, following error is shown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    client.write_points(json_body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\influxdb\client.py", line 364, in write_points
    tags=tags)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\influxdb\client.py", line 406, in _write_points
    expected_response_code=204
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\influxdb\client.py", line 277, in write
    expected_response_code=expected_response_code
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\influxdb\client.py", line 257, in request
    raise InfluxDBClientError(response.content, response.status_code)
InfluxDBClientError: 500: {"error":"database is required"}
```

Comment: Looks like your'e using version 0.9, double-check that you're using the docs for 0.9.  E.g., http://influxdb.com/docs/v0.9/concepts/reading_and_writing_data.html has a different format for the JSON body.

Comment: Yes I am using version 0.9

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the database and the retention policy to which the points should be written, as on the docs page Erik referenced:

For example:

```
{
    "database": "mydb",
    "retentionPolicy": "default",
    "points": [
        {
            "name": "cpu_load_short",
            "tags": {
                "host": "server01",
                "region": "us-west"
            },
            "time": "2009-11-10T23:00:00Z",
            "fields": {
                "value": 0.64
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If you are using someone else's Python API are you certain it's compatible with InfluxDB 0.9? Many clients are only compatible with 0.8.x and there are significant breaking changes to the API between the two versions.

Comment: Yes the API is compatible with InfluxDB 0.9. Now I am getting another error: ` **raise InfluxDBClientError(response.content, response.status_code)
influxdb.client.InfluxDBClientError: 500: {"error":"json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []client.Point"}**`