# Status code 400 on post message to influxdb

Tags: python, json, post, influxdb, http-status-code-400

I'm trying to post a json file to influxdb on my local host. This is the code:

```
import json
import requests
url = 'http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb'
files ={'file' : open('sample.json', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
print(r.text)
```

This is what `sample.json` looks like:

```
    {
            "region" : "eu-west-1",
            "instanceType": "m1.small"
    }
```

My response gives the following errors:

```
 {"error":"unable to parse '--1bee44675e8c42d8985e750b2483e0a8\r': 
 missing fields\nunable to parse 'Content-Disposition: form-data;
 name=\"file\"; filename=\"sample.json\"\r': invalid field 
 format\nunable   to parse '\r': missing fields\nunable to parse '{': 
 missing fields\nunable to parse '\"region\" : \"eu-west-1\",':  invalid 
 field format\nunable to parse '\"instanceType\": \"m1.small\"':  invalid 
 field format\nunable to parse '}': missing fields"}
```

My json seems to be a valid json file. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the fault maybe is that you just open the file but not read it. I mean since you want to post the content of the `json` object which is stored on the file, and not the file itself, it may be better to do that instead:

```
import json
import requests
url = 'http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb'
json_data = open('sample.json', 'rb').read()   # read the json data from the file
r = requests.post(url, data=json_data) # post them as data
print(r.text)
```

which is actually your code modified just a bit...

Comment: Thanks, this did help get rid of this error. However, now I'm getting an InfluxDB error - {"error":"database is required"}

Comment: @TracyAnnMonteiro  ,This is an issue that has to do with the `InfluxDB`.
You can see more here:
https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/2127
   and some helpful information to resolve this are in this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227901/internal-server-error-while-entering-points-using-json-in-influxdb

Answer (score 0):

Writing data with JSON was deprecated for performance reasons and has since been removed.

See GitHub issue comments [107043910](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/pull/2696#issuecomment-107043910).

Comment: Yes you are correct. Saw this after I posted the problem. Thank you.